# latitude and longitude change in android and map not shown 

Tags: android

latitude and longitude change in android and map not shown

```
package net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity {
    MapView mapView;
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p;
    double latPoint, lngPoint;
    LocationManager myManager;


class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    @Override

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
    {   
        //---when user lifts his finger---
        if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
            GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                (int) event.getX(),
                (int) event.getY());

            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    p.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                    p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                String add = "";
                if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); 
                         i++)
                       add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                }
                Log.e("address", add);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            return true;
        }
        else                
            return false;
    }        

}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.zoom);
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls();

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();
     LocationManager myManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    myManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,new myLocationListener());


    mc.setZoom(10);

    //---Add a location marker---
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);   

    mapView.invalidate();

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

class myLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void ListLocationUpdater() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (myManager != null) {
            // List list = myManager.getAllProviders();
            String param = (String) myManager.getProviders(true).get(0);
            loc = myManager.getLastKnownLocation(param);
            if (loc != null) {
                latPoint = loc.getLatitude();
                lngPoint = loc.getLongitude();
                                    p = new GeoPoint((int) (latPoint * 1E6), (int) (lngPoint * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);                    Log.e("RootDrawApplication",String.valueOf(latPoint)+"  , "+String.valueOf(lngPoint));

            } else
                Log.e("GoogleMaps ", "Error: Location  is null");
        } else
            Log.e("GoogleMaps ", "Error: Location Manager is null");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a location listener to your location manager with this code:

```
myManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                    0, new myLocationListener());
```

This way, your myLocationListener will implement the locationListener interface and change Location in onLocationChangedFunction.

```
public class myLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public ListLocationUpdater() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //assign location here
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: if i put the my code in the OnLocationChange() of  myLocationListener class it will provide error please correct me where to put my above code.

Comment: i past my code because not build the application.
it is does not build ( build error is : myLocationListener cannot be resolved to a type, 3 quick fixes 1) change to LocationListener(anroid.listener) 
2) create a class myLocationListener
3) fix the project setup.

Comment: the same error is come at the below line
 myManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new myLocationListener());

myLocationListener is cannot be resovled type. it is does not build. please help me

Comment: i saw your code. i find your myManager is not declared in as a field of class plz make it as field instead of local variable and relax we are here

Comment: hi the error is cleared but map is not shown instead of a blue screen only shown i edit my question and  paste my code and logcat please revise it and help me.

Comment: it is not in zoom level however i see the logcat there is no log.e() message print. i put log.e in if(loc!=null){ ... log.e(..) }  i paste logcat here and i  my paste the code by editing quesion please check it.

Comment: if you are getting location is null then ur gps service is not working properly try to move you phone to diff location and then check

Comment: for other map application like show current location is working well. is there mistake in my code? plz check it. i checked i do not know what is problem

Answer (score 2):

Create a backgroud thread and check the gps data there.
And use a LocationListener:

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
      public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
         TextView tv = new TextView(gpstracker.this);
         tv.setText("lat: " + l.getLatitude() + "\nlon: " + l.getLongitude());
         setContentView(tv);
      }
      ...
```

[This](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=de&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://www.smart-developer.de/Online/Artikel/Eigener-GPS-Tracker-mit-dem-Android-SDK) can also help...

Comment: i have one doubt is thread run every seconds... i do not know much about thread and i am not working before in thread . please correct me

Comment: how to use it please help me.